# What is the best practice to set variables on the app with new carbon-route element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit, carbon-route

In the polymer starter kit the whole app is wrapped in a template (id="app") as follows:

```
<body unresolved>
 <span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
 <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
   ...
   <!-- One of my custom elements -->
   <position-el id="editElemID" position-id="[[params.posId]]"></position-el>
   ...
 </template>
</body>
```

One of the ways I benefit from this style is that I can set some variables on the app when the route changes as follows:

```
page('/position/:posName/:posId/edit', function(data) {
  app.route = 'positionEdit';
  app.$.editElemID.edit = true;
  app.params = data.params;
});
```

Can I set variables on the app level in a similar way using the new carbon-route element?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, carbon-route exposes a `data` param with the captured `:segments` of the URL pattern. These are exposed for easy data binding and observing.